# Mvvm light - cannot to configure navigations

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a problem with `navigationService` and `navigationService.Configure`

In my `ViewModelLocator` constructor I have:

```
var navigationService = new NavigationService();
navigationService.Configure("MvvmView",new Uri("/MvvmView1.xaml"));
navigationService.Configure("Main",new Uri("/MainPage.xaml"));

SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => navigationService);
```

`MvvmView1.xaml` is in my main folder, the same as `MainPage.xaml`.

What is strange - it returns me an error

> {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'SpaceQuiz.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator' threw an exception. --->
>   System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could
>   not be determined.
>
> at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean
>   dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)    at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString) 
>   at SpaceQuiz.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator..cctor()    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at
>   MS.Internal.TypeProxy.<>c__DisplayClass32.b__2c()
>   at MS.Internal.TypeProxy.CreateInstance(UInt32 customTypeId)    at
>   MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.CreateInstance(XamlTypeToken
>   inXamlType, XamlQualifiedObject& newObject)}

I tried a lot of combinations, like:

```
navigationService.Configure("MvvmView",new Uri("MvvmView1.xaml"));
navigationService.Configure("MvvmView",new Uri("/MvvmView1"));
navigationService.Configure("MvvmView",new Uri("MvvmView1"));
navigationService.Configure("MvvmView",new Uri("./MvvmView1.xaml"));
navigationService.Configure("MvvmView",new Uri("/MvvmView"));
```

etc - without any success..

How to register navigation in mvvm light?

Any help would be valuable.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Mvvm Light v 5.0.2 I Believe you should not use an URI as the second parameter, it should rather be the `Typeof(view)`. First you define a string constant for each view class and then configure the **navigationservice** like this:

```cs
//This is in the ViewModelLocator.cs

// Define one key for each view/page. 
// You can call them anything but I use my view/class name followed by "Key"

public const string MvvmView1Key  = "MvvmView1"; 

var nav = new NavigationService();

//Updated to reflect SilverLight instead of Store App.
nav.Configure("MvvmView1", new Uri("/MvvmView1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

// Assuming that your view class is called MvvmView1.
```

Comment: I'm using version `Assembly GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll, v5.0.2.32241`, but I cannot use `Typeof(View)` - only `public void Configure(string key, Uri targetUri);`..

Comment: Oh - ok. My mistake sorry (I was thinking WP81 Store App and not Silverlight). In that case try this: nav.Configure("MvvmView1", new Uri("/MvvmView1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); It works fine for me.